# Processing many csv files adding metadata in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a 20 files csv looks that:

```
Value Value2
A       B
C       D
etc.
```

Files are in three different folders. 2 are in folder MI, 4 in MB and rest in W. 
I have a list of all path. I use that code to got it:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\User\ab"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".col"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Example paths looks that:

```
C:\User\ab\mb\432432\Out\xxxxx.col 
C:\User\ab\mb\787878\Out\xxxxx.col
C:\User\ab\mi\3114\Out\xxxxx.col 
C:\User\ab\w\2312\Out\xxxxx.col
```

Above I contains path only for four file, there is 20. 
What I need to do:

I need to create one DF contains all above DFs. But I need to add column with folder name and sample name (sample name is the number in path after dir name).

So whole DF will have that structure:

```
Value    Value2   Dir   Number
    A       B     MB    432432
    C       D     MB    432432
    G       E     MB    787878
    G       E     MB    787878
    F       O     W      22222
    F       O     W      22222
    etc.
```

Is there a simple way to do that? I tried many ways but i think my logic is not proper. Can someone give me some advice how can I do it in fast way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I did understood your problem correctly.
If you are trying to fetch files from different folders, and get information from the path, you could do the following:

```
import glob

all_files = glob.glob('C:\User\ab\*\*\Out\*.col')

for file in all_files:
    meta = file.split('\')
    dir = meta[3]
    nmbr = meta[4]
```

This snippet searches for the respective files (note that `glob` allows for wildcard search). You can than iterate over your files and extract the information you need from the path by splitting it.
Afterwards, you can open the file, read every row and append the respective information to it and save it to a new csv file.